# How could I encrypt and decrypt a message with a single key?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I have implemented Diffie–Hellman  and I'm looking for a way to encrypt and decrypt messages with that key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diffie–Hellman key exchange is a protocol to enable both sides to agree on a key.

You can use this key for any symmetric encryption algorithm. AES is the current standard.

AES accepts 128,192, and 256 bits size keys. When you agreed on a key, make sure that your protocol cut the keys for appropriate sizes for the symmetric encryption algorithm.